# Mysql insert lock wait timeout exceeded - auto increment

Tags: python, mysql, innodb

I'm having an issue with my application causing MySQL table to be locked due to inserts which take a long time, after reviewing online articles, it seems like it's related to auto increment, info below -

Python that inserts data (row at a time unfortunately as I need the auto incremented id for reference in future inserts) -

```
for i, flightobj in stats[ucid]['flight'].items():
            flight_fk = None
            # Insert flights
            try:
                with mysqlconnection.cursor() as cursor:
                    sql = "insert into cb_flights(ucid,takeoff_time,end_time,end_event,side,kills,type,map_fk,era_fk) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
                    cursor.execute(sql, (
                    ucid, flightobj['start_time'], flightobj['end_time'], flightobj['end_event'], flightobj['side'],
                    flightobj['killnum'], flightobj['type'], map_fk, era_fk))
                    mysqlconnection.commit()
                    if cursor.lastrowid:
                        flight_fk = cursor.lastrowid
                    else:
                        flight_fk = 0
            except pymysql.err.ProgrammingError as e:
                logging.exception("Error: {}".format(e))
            except pymysql.err.IntegrityError as e:
                logging.exception("Error: {}".format(e))
            except TypeError as e:
                logging.exception("Error: {}".format(e))
            except:
                logging.exception("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

The above runs every 2 minutes on the same data and is supposed to insert only non duplicates as the MySQL would deny duplicates due to the unique ucid_takeofftime index.

MYSQL info, cb_flights table -

```
  `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ucid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `takeoff_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_event` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `side` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kills` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `era_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `round_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ucid_takeofftime` (`ucid`,`takeoff_time`),
  KEY `ucid_idx` (`ucid`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `end_event` (`end_event`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `side` (`side`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76023132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now inserts into the table from the Python code, can take sometimes over 60 seconds.
I beleive it might be related to the auto increment that is creating the lock on the table, if so, I'm looking for a workaround.

innodb info -

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
```

buffer is used up to 70% more or less.

Appreciate any assistance with this, either from application side or MySQL side.

EDIT
Adding the create statement for the cb_kills table which is also used with inserts but without an issue as far as I can see, this is in response to the comment on the 1st answer.

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_kills` (
  `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `killer_ucid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `killer_side` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `killer_unit` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `victim_ucid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `victim_side` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `victim_unit` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weapon` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flight_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kill_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ucid_killid_flightfk_uniq` (`killer_ucid`,`flight_fk`,`kill_id`),
  KEY `flight_kills_fk_idx` (`flight_fk`),
  KEY `killer_ucid_fk_idx` (`killer_ucid`),
  KEY `victim_ucid_fk_idx` (`victim_ucid`),
  KEY `time_ucid_killid_uniq` (`time`,`killer_ucid`,`kill_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `flight_kills_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`flight_fk`) REFERENCES `cb_flights` (`pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52698582 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Not likely to fix your problem, but why not create one cursor outside the loop instead of creating a new one on each iteration?

Comment: "Now inserts into the table from the Python code, can take sometimes over 60 seconds", - this may indicate the problem. A single INSERT cannot take that long no matter how large table is. I suspect the insert is waiting for an X lock which can't be granted if other trxs hold S or X lock. Here's an idea - can you check the query in the slow log and post its summary? What's lock wait time comparing to total exec time?

Comment: Thanks @akuzminsky. 
Basically following your input, I checked the slow logs, it only showed the insert above as taking a long time, didn't find anything else locking etc... but that directed me to check the transactions, there I found out that a SP which is running an insert into a different table but selects from cb_flights is the one which is locking due to the insert select statement. this was running every 10 minutes or so with the event scheduler, I updated the SP to use temporary tables instead and now everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Remember you have available for deadlock detection, A) innodb_deadlock_detect=ON and B) innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON to have details in your error log.  Would not be a bad idea to have both on always and check the error log daily, weekly or monthly to be aware when a new one has reared it's ugly head.

Comment: "insert only non duplicates" -- Be aware that it only checks the unique keys to decide if a row is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to put in here some of the ways I worked on finding a solution to this problem. I'm not an expert in MySQL but I think these steps can help anyone looking to find out why he has lock wait timeouts.

So the troubleshooting steps I took are as follows -

1- Check if I can find in the MySQL slow log the relevant query that is locking my table. Usually it's possible to find queries that run a long time and also locks with the info below and the query right after it

```
# Time: 2020-01-28T17:31:48.634308Z
# User@Host: @ localhost [::1]  Id: 980397
# Query_time: 250.474040  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 195738
```

2- The above should give some clue on what's going on in the server and what might be waiting for a long time. Next I ran the following 3 queries to identify what is in use:

- check process list on which process are running -

`show full processlist;`

- check tables in use currently -

`show open tables where in_use>0;`

- check running transactions -

`` SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_trx` ORDER BY `trx_started`; ``

3- The above 2 steps should give enough information on which query is locking the tables. in my case here I had a SP that ran an `insert into <different table> select from <my locked table>`, while it was inserting to a totally different table, this query was locking my table due to the select operation that took a long time.
To work around it, I changed the SP to work with temporary tables and now although the query is still not completely optimized, there are no locks on my table.

Adding here how I run the SP on temporary tables for async aggregated updates.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `procedureName`()
BEGIN
    drop temporary table if exists scheme.temp1;
    drop temporary table if exists scheme.temp2;
    drop temporary table if exists scheme.temp3;
    create temporary table scheme.temp1 AS select * from scheme.live1;
    create temporary table scheme.temp2 AS select * from scheme.live2;
    create temporary table scheme.temp3 AS select * from scheme.live3;
    create temporary table scheme.emptytemp (
      `cName1` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `cName2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `cName3` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `cName4` datetime NOT NULL,
      `cName5` datetime NOT NULL,
      KEY `cName1` (`cName1`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

    INSERT into scheme.emptytemp
    select t1.x,t2.y,t3.z
    from scheme.temp1 t1
    JOIN scheme.temp2 t2
    ON t1.x = t2.x
    JOIN scheme.temp3 t3
    ON t2.y = t3.y

    truncate table scheme.liveTable;
    INSERT into scheme.liveTable
    select * from scheme.emptytemp;
END
```

Hope this helps anyone that encounters this issue

Comment: Note that this approach leave the table empty briefly.  That can be remedied by suitable use of `RENAME TABLE`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#optimal_reload_of_a_table

Answer (score 1):

You can check if autocommit is set to 1, this forces to commit every row and disabling it makes it somewhat faster

Instead of committing every insert try to bulk insert.

For that you should check
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

and do something like

```
data = [
('city 1', 'MAC', 'district 1', 16822),
('city 2', 'PSE', 'district 2', 15642),
('city 3', 'ZWE', 'district 3', 11642),
('city 4', 'USA', 'district 4', 14612),
('city 5', 'USA', 'district 5', 17672),
]

sql = "insert into city(name, countrycode, district, population) 
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"

number_of_rows = cursor.executemany(sql, data)
db.commit()
```

Comment: This is a problem as I need the returned lastrow for every insert, mentioned it in the original description.

Comment: that's a problem, is it possible to add all inserts the vertical ones, for that you save the lastinsert_id, to do in one insert and use a after insert trigger to split the data to all tables Else i see only faster hardware.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem to through more RAM at it, server I'm using has 64GB, but I doubt it would get to inserts of seconds?

Comment: It is hard to tell. check the mysql logs, if there is a problem and check the system if it has encounter problems, i usually check also the s.m.a.r.t Information of the harddrive, also after a backup try to optimize the tables if you can manage to stop the insert for maintenance. I can't see a way without bulk insert. But the question is young You can always try a bounty.

Comment: Could you describe how you need to use the last inserted Id? Like do you need in returned to a script or does it need to be stored somewhere else in the database?

Comment: So the returned id is then used in another table - cb_kills as ref to this inserted flight. 
As addition to the loop on flights above, there's afterwards a loop on kills which are inserted one by one as well, in that table I do not have the insert issue, and i also use the auto increment. make me wonder maybe there's something else that is effecting it the cb_flights table, but I'm not sure how to check it